# How can I set UI widgets in a second window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to dynamically set a QList of files (or strings) in a second window that appears after Login (LoginWindow), via Qt.
The second window is a QDialog.
How can I interact with UI of LsWindow  (second window) ?
I've alredy tried with a setUi() functions in LsWindow.h, but it doesn't run.

```cpp
void LoginWindow::on_loginButton_clicked(){
    // testing login

    this->close();  // close login window

    QStringList strList;  //construct string list
    strList.push_back("A");
    strList.push_back("B");

        QListWidget* l;  // creating a widget
    l->addItems(strList);

    LsWindow* ls = new LsWindow(this);
    ls->show();

    //ls.ui.listWidget = l;   (??)

    ls->exec();
}



//LsWindow class implementation
class LsWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LsWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~LsWindow();


private:
    Ui::LsWindow ui;
};
```

Comment: you do not create QlistWidget, you declare pointer to it, without initialization, and then you attempt to call method via this pointer. I'm pretty sure it is undefined behavior

Comment: could you post your LsWindow class implementation?

Comment: @AndrewKashpur yes, but I can't refer to QListWidget into UI of LsWindow. Or if I could, how?

Comment: @Zharios I added LsWindow class implementation, all the elements are setted in ui_LsWindow.h using Qt designer.

Comment: @leort first of all i think that you don't need ls->show(). Only ls->exec() must work